# Refresh page on react-router outputs blank page, bundle.js is not loaded

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I can access all paths as long as I do not refresh the page. When I refresh the page however, I get a blank page with no errors. I have looked through a number of answers related to this issue, but I was unable to find a solution that worked for my setup.

I'm using react-router and express, I have set `historyApiFallback: true` and `publicPath: '/'`. I checked the console after the page is refreshed, and there is no bundle.js loaded, only index.html is loaded - which explains the blank page. I hope someone can shed some light on this.

**folder structure**

```
public
-- index.html
src
-- client
-- server
   -- index.js
webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const outputDirectory = 'dist';

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true
          }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ],
      include: /\.module\.scss$/
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      exclude: /\.module\.scss$/
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
    }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/': 'http://localhost:8080'
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputDirectory]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
    })
  ]
};
```

**server.js**

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')

const { logger, session } = require('./loader')
const auth = require('./api/middleware/authentication')
const { authRoute, sendRoute } = require('./api/routes')


const app = express();

app.use(session);

app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.static('dist'))

// API routes
app.use('/auth', authRoute)
app.use('/send', auth, sendRoute)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  logger.info(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`)
})
```

**App.js snippet**

```html
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact><LandingPage /></Route>
  <Route path="/login">
    <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
      <Login />
    </Container>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/end"><EndPage /></Route>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and was looking for a solution. I tried some stuff and it works in production and dev mode now. Dev mode got it to work by adding the `historyApiFallback: true` and `publicPath: '/'` (which you already have). For production mode see below. I am just a beginner and this is my first answer ever so please feel free to correct me.

In your express server file server.js (or index.js), I added this:

```
const path = require('path');

app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "path/to/your/index.html"), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Then, in the public index.html below the "root" div I added:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

I think it works because it'll send all requests back to index.html which now has that script of bundle.js but I'm not sure. On the main / page of the website it doesn't load the bundle.js twice which is cool.